# Is this a known functional programming paradigm?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I wrote a unary function which draws a pixel: `drawPixel`.

If the arg is an array, I want it to execute the code for each element of the array. If not an array, the code will execute once on the arg. Like this:

```
function drawPixel(pixel) {
  console.log(pixel);
}

function mapify(fn) {
  return maybeArray => {
    if (Array.isArray(maybeArray)) {
      return maybeArray.map(fn)
    } else {
      return fn(maybeArray)
    }
  }
}

const draw = mapify(drawPixel);

draw(3)
// 3
draw([1,2,3])
// 1
// 2
// 3
```

Is the map-ify function in this example a known pattern, perhaps under a different name?

Comment: I've just heard this called map -- as the name of the function

Comment: Additional detail on wikipedia including cross language comparison https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)

Comment: and as I'm sure you know having a function take multiple types of parameters is called polymorphism https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's just polymorphism. The fact I could write a generic function to implement the polymorphism (mapify) made me think it might be a known pattern.

Comment: I see this pattern a lot in javascript, but I don't think it has a special name.

Comment: Given that `drawPixel` has side effects, I wouldn't consider this to be "functional programming" at all

Comment: Aside from Bergi's comment about how `drawPixel` isn't functional at all, I think it's also a bit antithetical to functional programming and polymorphism to have a function that does explicit type checking to handle a value as either a list or a single value. I'd say your function signatures should usually be clearly defined, and list-or-single-value isn't a very well-defined type. If your function operates on lists, then you should pass a list into it: `draw([3])`.

Comment: yes. this is known as [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch). it's more a part of the object-oriented programming paradigm, not the functional programming paradigm.